# pre Python 3.4 HTML entity unescaping

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.x

**NOTE:** [This](https://gist.github.com/rolandshoemaker/8d1c2c26d62f9442b529) let's you do 3.4 HTML5 entity conversion on pre-3.4 Python versions!

I'm writing a parser+renderer for the CommonMark spec of Markdown and I'm trying to figure out the best way to escape HTML entities across various python versions.

For Python 3 I use `html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape` and for Python 2 I use `HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape`. They are essentially the same function, except the later Python versions have updated entity definition tables, because of this this string that works fine in Python 3.4

```
&#35;␣&#1234;␣&#992;␣&#98765432; => #␣Ӓ␣Ϡ␣�
```

results in this on Python 3.3 and 2

```
&#35;␣&#1234;␣&#992;␣&#98765432; => #␣Ӓ␣Ϡ␣&#98765432;
```

This also happens with various other HTML entities, ie

```
&Dcaron;␣&HilbertSpace;␣&DifferentialD;␣&ClockwiseContourIntegral;
```

I'm wondering if anyone know's of a way of doing this that's either cross-compatible, or works fine on pre 3.4 versions, that doesn't require 3rd party modules?

I'm trying to avoid having to basically copy over the entity table from python 3.4 and store it in a file somewhere :<

Comment: I fear the 'copying the entire table' is your only option if you don't want to rely on a 3rd party package (which may or may not exist).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of, oh well. Can't be that bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can you the Python library [html5charref](http://html5charref.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/bpabel/html5charref.git
```

Then use it as follows:

```
html = u'This has &copy; and &lt; and &#x000a9; symbols'
print html5charref.unescape(html)
# u'This has \uxa9 and < and \uxa9 symbols'
```